# Trying to use "if-else" statement in a const for a inline style, failed to compile error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an inline style that if true, I want to just display a part of state. But, if it is false, I want to run a function that is contained within a const which will give the definitive style.

However, when making the if-else statement within the const, I am getting a "failed to compile error" and I cannot figure out why.

The const in question is 'gradientChoice'

Any ideas at all?

Inline style:

```
<div
      className="App"
      style={{
        background: mode === "single" ? firstColorInput : gradientChoice,
      }}
    >
```

The const function I have:

```
  const gradientChoice = {
    if (gradientSelected === "linear") {
      `linear-gradient(${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput})`
    } else {
      `radial-gradient(${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput})`
    }
  };
```

States mentioned in the const:

```
const [degSlider, setDegSlider] = useState("90")
  const [firstColorInput, setFirstColorInput] = useState("")
  const [secondColorInput, setSecondColorInput] = useState("")
const [gradientSelected, setGradientSelected] = useState("linear")
```

Comment: That's not the syntax for an inline function, that's the syntax for an inline object.

Comment: You sure `gradientChoice` is a function? To me it is an object

Comment: ES6 arrow function looks like this `const gradientChoice = () => { return 'what you want'  };`

Comment: @JetCat Even if `gradientChoice` was a function, the OP isn't using `()` inside their JSX render function, so it would be output as `[Function]` - ew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code actually defines `gradientChoice` as an object (that's what `= {` does) however you can't have an `if` inside an object-literal.

Instead, use the ternary-operator: `<bool-expr> ? <when-true> : <when-false>`.

```
const gradientChoice = ( gradientSelected === "linear" ) ?
    `linear-gradient(${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput})`
    :
    `radial-gradient(${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput})`
;
```

This can be simplified to this:

```
const gradientChoice = `${ gradientSelected === "linear" ? "linear-gradient" : "radial-gradient" }( ${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput} )`;
```

Personally I'd do it like this to reduce the total line-length:

```
const gradientFunc = gradientSelected === "linear" ? "linear-gradient" : "radial-gradient";

const gradientChoice = `${ gradientFunc }( ${degSlider}deg, ${firstColorInput}, ${secondColorInput} )`;
```